# How do I add options to the Tabs preferences?

Tags: safari-extension

I would like my new tabs created with command-T to open immediately to the right of my current tab, not all the way to the right.  I've looked at a lot of tutorials online, but I haven't seen any that work with the internals of Safari like this.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Safari extension: http://canisbos.com/taboptions. It's old but still works on latest Safari.

Comment: Thanks, that does what I want.  I'm still curious about how to implement it myself.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Sean, well, I don't think it can be done without a Safari extension. You could extract the source files from the Tab Options extension and see how it works — but, caveat, it was written long before the new extension framework in which extensions are more like native Mac apps.